# Is it possible to transfer data between an app in two different iOS devices?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, ios8

Let the app name SampleApp and it is present in two iPhones. Is it possible to share data between these two devices such that only the SampleApp can receive the data being send?.

Assume, I have an private collection of photos and I would like to share it with my another family member having the same app(App being developed by me). Then how can I do this?

Comment: Look at the Multipeer Connectivity framework. Though it doesn't support iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do so with Core Bluetooth...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257

Bluetooth is the ideal way to transfer data between two devices and you are the one (the developer) managing what and how you transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

We can do so with Multipeer framework, only thing we need to have in common is service type.